Why I can't nullify many-to-one attribute with EclipseLink?
I'm working on SpringBoot-based platform which uses EclipseLink as ORM.
In my main entity there is a attribute represents ManyToOne association with another entity. Attribute has the following annotations:
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "unit_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
protected Dict unit;

The problem occurs when I try to update existing main entity.
There're two scenarios of updating:

I set null value for unit attribute
I replace old unit value with another one

In both scenarios I set some new values for other fields and it saved correctly.
After main entity saved by calling entity = repository.save(entity); I call getUnit() method for entity object and for the first scenario it returns old value of unit (this old value also stored in DB instead of null) though I expect null as returned value, but for the second scenario it returns new value of unit, as expected, and in DB this new value stored too. Because of that it seems there is no problem with transaction.
There're no exceptions during execution. During debugging of the first scenario I see null value for unit attribute of entity object until getUnit() method is called. The corresponding field in DB table is nullable. HSQLDB used as DB during tests.
So what's the problem? Why I can't nullify unit attribute and corresponding DB field?

It should work - Are there other mappings to the "unit_id" fk column in your entity? After nulling the reference and committing the transaction, is the column in the DB updated - by that could it just be you are checking via a cached instance from an EntityManager that may have the stale entity reference still? Do you maybe have methods, accessors or callbacks on the 'other side' within the Dict entity that might reset the reference?

@Chris There are no other mappings. About transaction commiting: calling repository.save() performs in private method of service class, so it cannot be @Transactional. @Transactional is a public method of service class which call some methods before save and after save. I don't think there is a problem with transaction because if I change unit_id with another non-null value everything works fine. The problem occured only for null value - looks like null value just ignored. There're nothing special on the Dict entity's side.

You have cascade all set - do you maybe have it on other relationships as well? If I were to guess, it'd be that you are passing in a large object graph, and possibly have a situation where a1->b1->a1'. If a1 has the null set but you are cascading the save over to b1 which reference a different instance of a1 that still has the reference, it will undo your change. If that isn't it or doesn't help, maybe detail how you are fetching the instance and then setting the reference to null - turn on EclipseLink logging and see what queries it issues.

@Chris My object graph is only a1->b1, so the relation is unidirectional. There is no any mapping in Dict to the second entity. EclipseLink logs show that if I change value for unit to another, then corresponding field unit_id is present in UPDATE SQL command, but if I try to change unit to null value, then field unit_id not present in UPDATE SQL command.

I found that I can't nullify not only field with ManyToOne association but every nullable field in my entity. The reason of such behaviour was that I tried to save detached entity, created from scratch and filled by values from request. Similar situation answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9911568/9463937. I will looking a way to rework my service.

This issue is the opposite of the issue the answer is explaining. In the linked Q/A, the issue was with all values not being set were being nulled out, while in this case, you can't null them out at all. There should be no problem nulling out an entry in a detached entity and merging it back in - if there is, you'll have to check the state of the entity after the merge, and see if any accessor methods might be preventing it
